# Browser doesn't initiate properly - iim.Init() failed?

Tags: vba, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, imacros

I'm trying to port code from an old laptop to a new Windows 8 machine.  All of my VBA / iMacros scripts work perfectly on the old machine.  I'm calling iMacros from inside a VBA script.  I'm running Windows 8 and iMacros 8, Scripting Edition (standalone browser).

The sticking point is that my Windows 8 machine doesn't recognize open instances of iMacros.  When I run iim.init() with the "False" condition, it should recognize and run macros in the open instance.  Instead, it opens a new (but crippled) instance of iMacros that doesn't even load the homepage (nor subsequently run any scripts).  The error I get is "Browser was not started. iimInit() failed?"

Has anyone else had the same problem?  What's the solution?  Code:

```
Dim iim1, iret

Set iim1 = CreateObject("imacros")
iret = iim1.iimInit("", False, "")

iret = iim1.iimPlay("My_Macro")

If iret < 0 Then
   MsgBox iim1.iimGetLastError()
End If
```

BTW, I'm aware that iMacros 8 doesn't support Internet Explorer 10 (whose exclusive installation is enforced by Windows 8).  I've tried my macros with IE10 enabled and disabled.  I don't think IE10 is the issue, since iMacros browser is fully end-user functional with IE10 disabled--i.e. runs scripts, loads webpages.

Comment: Try to experiment with `GetObject` instead of `CreateObject`. The first one is to catch opened instance of application and use it. Second creates new one, like in your situation.